# Python Keras - How to generate right image dimension

Tags: python-2.7, keras

I'm tying to use Keras for image recognition, but kept getting errors like:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_9 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 300, 300)

I tried to change values for params that relate to dimensions, also tried to reshape images, but still got errors. 
**In fact, I don't understand why did I get this error. Why it expects 4 dimensions?**

Here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import sklearn
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Convolution2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Reshape, InputLayer
import cv2
from skimage import io

import urllib2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
```

I chose 50 rose images and 50 sunflower images from imagenet:

```
rose_file = "http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n04971313"
sunflower_file = "http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n11978713"

images = []
image_num = 50

rose_urls = urllib2.urlopen(rose_file)
rose_ct = 0
for rose_url in rose_urls: 
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(rose_url)
        rose_image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
        images.append(rose_image)
        rose_ct += 1
        if rose_ct == image_num:  # only use 50 images here, otherwise, loading time is too long
            break
    except:   # some images are no longer available
        pass

sunflower_urls = urllib2.urlopen(sunflower_file)
sunflower_ct = 0
for sunflower_url in sunflower_urls: 
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(sunflower_url)
        sunflower_image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
        images.append(sunflower_image)
        sunflower_ct += 1
        if sunflower_ct == image_num:   # only use 50 images here, otherwise, loading time is too long
            break
    except:   # some images are no longer available
        pass
```

Resize training images to 300*300:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i]=cv2.resize(np.array(images[i]),(300,300))

images = np.array(images)

labels = [0 for i in range(image_num)]
labels.extend([1 for j in range(image_num)])
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)
```

Build the model:

```
filters=10
filtersize=(5,5)

epochs=7
batchsize=128

input_shape=(300,300, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(filters, filtersize, strides=(1, 1), 
                                        padding='valid', data_format="channels_last", activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(images, labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batchsize, validation_split=0.3)

model.summary()
```

Here, I tried to change `input_shape=(300,300, 3)` into `input_shape=(300,300, 3, 0)`, hoping this means 4 dimensions, but got errors saying:

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_13: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

**Do you know why did I get these errors? And how to deal with this problem?**

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `input_shape=(300,300, 3)`. The problem is that `sunflower_image` and `rose_image` arrays do not have the correct shape. They should be 3D-arrays before being fed into `cv2.resize`. I think using `cv2.imread()` to load the files will solve the problem.

Comment: Could `imread` read urls? I tried that, it only supports reading the image files. Also, it seems that if it's colorful image instead of grey image, there could be more dimension...

Comment: Try this: `img = Image.open(resp).resize((300, 300)); rose_image = np.array(img); images.append(rose_image)`. Color images have more dimensions indeed, but you're flattening it into a 1D-array with `rose_image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")`. Check the shape of `rose_image` and you'll understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I tried to `imread` for local images, it works.